# How to remove active effect in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character has an active effect 'Reanimation', which probably originates from a reanimated corpse that somehow vanished, seemingly due to a bug (the 'Reanimation' spell is probably from Skyrim Redone).

Now I can not get rid of this effect any more. The remaining time of the 'Reanimation' effect is currently shown as 998 days.

Using the console command 'dispelallspells' works, but I don't want to use this because I have a lot of other effects, partly from mods, and I don't want to add them all manually again, and I am unsure about this command and its effects in general.

I tried to remove the 'Reanimation' spell, with player.removespell xyz, but this did not help, and the effect still lasts. I also tried to use the reanimation spell again on another corpse, but this had just the effect that I had two spells 'Reanimation' active.

Is there a way to get rid of this spell? I realized that the effect is active only because my conjuration level is constantly increasing. Unfortunately, I going back to a save game before the bug occured would loose a lot of game time.

Comment: I would contact the mod author and report this. It sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Pardon the necropost, but using "removespell" doesn't seem to work for me. What did work however, is simply using "dispel" instead of "dispelallspells", as this will only delete the effects for *a single spell*. For example:

1) Open console, type;

```
 help "(spell name)"
```

2) find the ID of the spell, whose effect you wish to cancel, and type;

```
 player.dispel <SpellID>
```

As I was having the same problem you were, I thought this might be of some help. I had "Reanimate Animal" active, even after the reanimated animal had bugged out and disappeared when zoning. Have fun with your adventures in Skyrim!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, adding the spell and removing it can solve this issue:

1. Open a console.
2. Run `player.addspell <SpellID>`
3. Close the console and re-open it.
4. Run `player.removespell <SpellID>`

This has been known to occasionally "unstick" bad spell effects that are applied to you.

---

If this fails, the easiest solution would be to `dispelallspells` and restore all spells through the console. This is best done through a script.

Answer (score -4):

If it is for being drunk - Use Console Command

Playidle IdleDrunkStop/<0x000cefd1>

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this solving the issue with the mod? I am pretty sure this is just a mod glitch.